# Setting images and text with ViewHolder

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm unable to access the image and audio array from getView() function. I've commented out the statements that i've tried. Those comments are located at the bottom of the code, before the ViewHolder class.

I've tried using statements like:

```
holder.imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
holder.textView.setText(audio[position]);
```

But the images and audio array are inaccessible from that location. How do I access them from getView()?

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MyList extends Fragment {

        ListView list;
        MediaPlayer mp;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedinstanceState)
        {
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.wave1);

            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistview, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {

            super.onStart();
            list=(ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity()));
            list.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                        long arg3) 
                {
                    switch(position)
                        {
                        case 0:
                            mp.release();
                            mp=MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.wave1);
                            mp.start();                         
                        }

                 }
                });
        }
    }

        class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
        {
            ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
            Context context;
            public MyAdapter(Context c)
            {
                context=c;
                list=new ArrayList<SingleRow>();

            Resources res=c.getResources();
            String[] audio=res.getStringArray(R.array.audio);

                int[] images={ 
                        R.drawable.image,
                };
                for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
                {
                    list.add(new SingleRow(audio[i],images[i]));
                } 
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return list.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return list.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {

                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View row=convertView;
                MyViewHolder holder=null;

                if(row==null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rows, parent, false);
                    holder=new MyViewHolder(row);

                    row.setTag(holder);
                }

                else 
                {
                    holder=(MyViewHolder)row.getTag();
                }


/* The following two statements don't work, because images and the audio array are not accessible.

            holder.imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
            holder.textView.setText(audio[position]);
*/
                return row;
            }

        class MyViewHolder
        {
            ImageView imageView;
            TextView textView;

            MyViewHolder(View v)
            {
                textView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                imageView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            }
        }

        class SingleRow
        {
            String audio;
            int image;
            SingleRow(String audio, int image)
            {
                this.audio=audio;
                this.image=image;
            }
        }

        }
```

**EDIT:**

The MyAdapter class now looks like the following. Now the application launches, but the fragment is empty, with no views at all.

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
    Context context;

    int[] images1 = null;
    String[] audio = null;
    public MyAdapter(Context c) {

        context=c;
        list=new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
        //Initialize them...
        Resources res=c.getResources();
        audio = res.getStringArray(R.array.audio);
        int[] images1={ 

                R.drawable.image,
                };

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            list.add(new SingleRow(audio[i],images1[i]));
        } 

    }



    Resources res=context.getResources();
    String[] audio=res.getStringArray(R.array.audio);



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row=convertView;
        MyViewHolder holder=null;

        if(row==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rows, parent, false);
            holder=new MyViewHolder(row);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }

        else 
        {
            holder=(MyViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

    holder.imageView.setImageResource(images1[position]);
    holder.textView.setText(audio[position]);

            return row;
    }

class MyViewHolder
{
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

    MyViewHolder(View v)
    {
        textView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        imageView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    }
}

class SingleRow
{
    String audio;
    int image;
    SingleRow(String audio, int image)
    {
        this.audio=audio;
        this.image=image;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Declare both at class level instead of inside class constructor then you are able to access in whole class. same as you are declare and initializing `context` and `list` in `MyAdapter` class

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Thanks for replying. After moving them out of the constructer, the             list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity())); catches a red line saying "The constructor MyAdapter(FragmentActivity) is undefined". So I tried 2 things. First, commented it out, and the application ran without any list view on screen (it was blank). Secondly, I tried creating an empty constructer as it's asking for, but the program crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
        Context context;
        //Just declare them as class members
        int[] images = null;
        String[] audio = null;
        public MyAdapter(Context c)
        {
            context=c;
            list=new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
            //Initialize them...
            Resources res=c.getResources();
            audio = res.getStringArray(R.array.audio);
            images1= new int[] { R.drawable.image };
//Noticed you only have an element, 
//while I do not recommend to hardcode the positions, 
//I added it for compilation's sake
                list.add(new SingleRow(audio[0],images[0]));
            //... And the rest
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but now on the application launch, the fragment is empty. There are no views.

Comment: Noticed there are a few errors and the code won't compile. Edited the answer to reflect that. about the fragment issue, make you you are attaching the fragment to the corresponding FragmentActivity:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html